# How to do bidirectional data sync b/w Azure postgresql & onPrem oracle DB

Tags: database, azure, oracle12c, azure-postgresql

I have an Oracle DB with data in onPrem and Azure Postgresql DB in cloud.
I really need data changes in Oracle to be reflected as near to real-time as possible in Azure Postgresql DB.
I need data changes in Azure Postgresql DB to be reflected as near to real-time as possible in OnPrem Oracle.

See the below diagram for more info.
[image: Architecture Diagram]

I am new to Azure-Postgresql.
I would appreciate any suggestions / insights.

Comment: Oracle's solution would be Golden Gate but that generally requires additional licenses.

Comment: Is it unidirectional or bi-directional?if any data insrted to azure DB will that to be synced to onPrem Oracle DB?

Comment: It can do heterogeneous bidirectional replication.  Before Oracle bought it, it was a separate company that was focused on real-time replication between heterogeneous data sources.

Comment: Any azure service which can perform sync beween onprem Oracle DB to Azure postgre and vice versa.

Comment: @ganthota, per my experience,  you can create a pipeline to copy/sync the data between   on-premise database and Azure Postgresql DB with [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). Then create a schedule trigger to run the pipeline every 5 mins. That's the closest way to data sync.

Comment: Hi @ganthota, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I started doing POC on your answer. Once its done i ll accept it.

Comment: @ga7202 could you please advise how you finally achieved this bi-directional synch?

Answer (score 3):

Just for now, there isn't a directly way to sync the data between on-premise Oracle database and Azure PostgreSQL database. You need use other ETL ways.

Per my experience, you can think about use [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction).It's used to transfer the data to achieve the data sync. You could follow this way:

1. Create a pipeline to copy the data from on-premise Oracle to Azure
   PostgreSQL.
2. Create a [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger) to run the pipeline, we can set the
   execution every 5 mins.

For on-premise dataset, you also need [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime).

Ref the tutorials:

1. [Copy data from and to Oracle by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure Database for PostgreSQL by using
   Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-postgresql)

You need to think about the cost and if it's acceptable to you.